# What is the limit of sortable fields in the iForels Database?

Tags: database, business-application, iforels

iForels should support multiple fields for sorting. Hovewer, when I try to sort my iForels Database by 3 columns it always delete previouse features from sort config.
Here is my request body: `{"config":{"filters":[],"sorting":{"63e162f4d9afbf6e733534e8":1}}}`

I try to include multiple rules inside sorting config and expect it would not be removed automaticaly but return sorted datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily sort your data by multiple fields, and there are no limits. iForels Database is a kind of fork from Lucene technology. It saves docs in operational memory. That's why it works much faster than MongoDB or SQL databases, even with sorting by multiple fields.

Actually, your config for API works for me. Add as many fields as you'd like. Just make sure you add objects where the prop name is feature_id, and the value is 1 or -1.

If you have this issue on the front end, make sure you turn ON the multisport option for your view. Please, check the screenshots.

Open View Config:
[image]

Select Multisort:
[image]

I hope you’ll find it helpful!